# Adding types to HTMLElements working with Svelte and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, dom, svelte, htmlelements

I'm working with Svelte and typescript, and I'd like to add type definitions to the html elements I'm referencing.

For example I have something like this:

```
<script>
let closeButtonEl;
let prevFocused;

[...]
prevFocused = document.activeElement;
[...]
</script>
[...]
<button bind:this={closeButtonEl}>Click me</button>
```

That is, I have a `closeButtonEl` which I know for sure is a button, and a `prevFocused` which is an HTMLElement with a `focus()` method.

What type should I use for each of them? And where is that kind of things documented?

Answer (score 2):

As Stephane mentioned, you can find a list of web interfaces at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API#interfaces. The actual type information comes from [lib.dom.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.dom.d.ts) which is [generated from the webidl files produced by Microsoft Edge](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator).

For the various element types, you'll want to look at the interfaces that start with "HTML". In this specific case, you care about `HTMLElement` and `HTMLButtonElement`.

Answer (score 1):

You can type the elements with one of the interfaces found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API#interfaces

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete the answer

Like previously said by Scot and Stephane, the types of those elements can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API#interfaces

And for this particular case, I found these two solutions:

```js
  let closeButtonEl: HTMLButtonElement;
  let prevFocusedEl: Element & { focus?: () => void };
```

`document.activeElement` is of the `Element` type, in this case I also define that it has a focus method.

THe other solution is to cast `document.activeElement` as an HTMLElement which comes with the focus() method, like this:

```js
  let closeButtonEl: HTMLButtonElement;
  let prevFocusedEl: HTMLElement;

  $: if (isOpen) {
    prevFocusedEl = <HTMLElement> document.activeElement;
    closeButtonEl && closeButtonEl.focus();
  }
```